# C# UWP Desktop Bridge start ffmpeg with command

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a UWP Application which starts a WPF app and communicates via AppServiceConnection which works well,
what I want to do is to start FFmpeg / FFplay with the command to play a video.

The code in the WPF app for starting FFmpeg / FFplay via AppServiceConnection

```
private void Connection_RequestReceivedAsync(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            var value = args.Request.Message["REQUEST"] as string;
            switch (value)
            {
                case "StartFFmpeg":
                    Test();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void Test()
        {
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\ffplay.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-i C:\Users\test\video.mp4";


            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
        }
```

this fails with the following error in the UWP app:

```
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[16824] FFmpeg.Bridge.exe' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).
```

now my question is, is it possible to start FFmpeg / FFplay with the desktop bridge? or can we only start .net core processes, the process is running with full privileges so why is that not possible?

The UWP App won't be published on the store, it will only run on a local windows machine.

Comment: Does the code work as is when you run the WPF app outside of desktop bridge?

Comment: Yes the code runs fine without the Desktop Bridge, would it help if i had a WPF Core app ?

Comment: dont understand the downvote :( is there any code missing ?

Comment: Is it feasible to start other processes, such as starting an outlook?

Comment: What line raises that exception? Is the WPF app built with .NET Core or .NET Framework?